# Finding the second point of a vector knowing the magnitude

Tags: vectors

Points $A$ and $B$ lie in a plane, and $A$ has coordinates $(6, -2)$.
Find four possible positions for $B$ such that $\lVert AB\rVert = \sqrt{13}$

How do I apply Pythagoras Theorem to this?

Comment: Hint: use the distance formula.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I know there need to be a number of equations with the distance formula, but I can't figure out what the different formulas need to look like.

Comment: if we draw a circle with $A$ as center and radius $\sqrt{13}$, then all points on this circle can be your $B$. Equation of such a circle is $(x-6)^2+(y+2)^2=13$. Left side is the square of the distance from the center to any point $(x,y)$ and right side is the square of the radius.

Comment: @AnuragA Now that I know the equation of a circle how do I find coordinates on the circumference of the circle which are whole numbers?

Comment: @user10764803 to get coordinates with whole numbers you may need to try some patterns (unless you know some modular arithmetic). For example, $3^2+2^2=13$. This means we can take $x-6 =\pm 3$ and $y+2 = \pm 2$. Now this will give you some values of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

To find whole-number solutions, you look for integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m^2+n^2=13$. This shouldn't take you too long. This gives you eight suitable points (assuming $m\ne n$):
$(6\pm m, -2\pm n)$ and $(6\pm n, -2\pm m)$.

If this is not clear to you, just construct a couple of those points and compute their distance to $A$, and you will see how it works.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you derive m and n, how do you find the points, can you walk me through the process is greater detail? Thanks

Comment: I put some effort into making my answer as clear as I could. I am not going to spend more time on it.